# DIV moves out of line for no reason?

Tags: css, html

I can't figure this out.

I have 4 `divs` set to `display:inline-block`. For some reason the bottom left div wants to mis-align itself.

The HTML looks clean. As does the CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/ineedhalp/CJtDN/

```
<section class="top" data-type="background" data-speed="10" class="pages">
        <section id="s">
            <div class="title">Services</div>
                <div class="service">
                    <div class="serviceTitle"><h2>Domain & Hosting</h2></div>
                    <div class="serviceText"><p>Need to set up a domain name and web hosting account? Not sure where to start? Leave it to me!</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <div class="serviceTitle"><h2>Bespoke Design</h2></div>
                    <div class="serviceText"><p>Web design which enhances your individual or business's image and caters to your target audience's needs.</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <div class="serviceTitle"><h2>Responsive Design</h2></div>
                    <div class="serviceText"><p>I make sure your site looks great no matter which device it is viewed on, bringing you and your website into the mobile world.</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="service">
                    <div class="serviceTitle"><h2>Maintenance</h2></div>
                    <div class="serviceText"><p>Maintaining and updating your web presense is a necessity that can often be overlooked. Leave the task to me for a set monthly fee.</p></div>
                </div>      
         </section>
</section>

.service {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:20px;
    background:pink;    
}

.serviceTitle {
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:600;
    width:400px;
    height:56px;
    color:#fff;
    background:url(../_images/title.png);
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.serviceText {
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align:top` to your div elements.

Comment: Just beat me to it, +1. :] Here is a fiddle for the effort, http://jsfiddle.net/CJtDN/1/.

Comment: Great! Thanks! It was strange because it was already working fine until I simplified it down a bit, then it started acting up. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Set div.service css with vertical-align:top;

Answer (score 0):

This is done simply without css add the align section to your div as follows:

```
<div align="left">
\\or
<div align="right">
\\or
<div align="center">
\\etc...
```

add to each div tag so it would look like this:

```
<section class="top" data-type="background" data-speed="10" class="pages">
        <section id="s">
            <div align="left" class="title">Services</div>
                <div align="left" class="service">
                    <div align="left" class="serviceTitle"><h2>Domain & Hosting</h2></div>
                    <div align="left" class="serviceText"><p>Need to set up a domain name and web hosting account? Not sure where to start? Leave it to me!</p></div>
                </div>
                <div align="left" class="service">
                    <div align="left" class="serviceTitle"><h2>Bespoke Design</h2></div>
                    <div align="left" class="serviceText"><p>Web design which enhances your individual or business's image and caters to your target audience's needs.</p></div>
                </div>
                <div align="left" class="service">
                    <div align="left" class="serviceTitle"><h2>Responsive Design</h2></div>
                    <div align="left" class="serviceText"><p>I make sure your site looks great no matter which device it is viewed on, bringing you and your website into the mobile world.</p></div>
                </div>
                <div align="left" class="service">
                    <div align="left" class="serviceTitle"><h2>Maintenance</h2></div>
                    <div align="left"class="serviceText"><p>Maintaining and updating your web presense is a necessity that can often be overlooked. Leave the task to me for a set monthly fee.</p></div>
                </div>      
         </section>
</section>
```

This is for left alignment and just change according to the first set of tags i wrote to suit your needs